# Pressing Back Button should close app,should not Stop

Tags: android

In android if I press back button,I want to close the Application,But I don't want to stop that(ie., Clear information) ,Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use android `service` to achieve  it. You can find good tutorial of `service` [here.](http://techblogon.com/simple-android-service-example-code-description-start-stop-service/) and documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is the default Android behaviour and users are expected to know this.

You didn't mention your exact use case, but if you want your code to run even after the user left your app's UI, then use a Service. Or if you simply want to restore the state of the UI to the way the user left it, save that state to disk using e.g. SharedPreferences, SQLite, raw file I/O, etc.